# How to export database data to excel file using node.js?

Tags: node.js

How can i export the table stored in a database into an excel file using node.js? 
I don't know how to build connection with the database and create a table in excel that looks like the table in database.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAXlo.gif)

Thanks

Comment: This is highly dependent on the shape of your data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in node.js, but regarding the Excel part of your question: if you don't need a very complex sheet, then the simplest thing is to output the information in a command separated list, like:

> header1,header2,...
>
> value1,value2,...

Save it as .csv and Excel will be able to open it.